# How can I let my users send email from my django app?

Tags: django, email

I have a django app and users can create a profile and upload their contacts.

Is there a way for me to allow them to send email using their email account but through the app?

The use case would be that a user would like to send 50 emails to its contacts that are sent through his own email thought.

As i write this, I feel this is not possible - lol

Comment: Yes you can, for example using [gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#python_2). Just use this process in your django app.

Comment: Does it mean that you want to replace their normal e-mail application by your own ?

Comment: Ok, so I looked up the Gmail API that you linked and it actually partially solves the issue because it require the user to download credentials and allow for API usage AND it also force the user to authenticate every once in a while. I am looking for something that doesn't require to make weird work on the user side and can run for a while after being authenticate once. Suggestions?